# Fitting multiple linear models to all observations in a dataframe using purrr::map

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to learn more about the functionalities of R's `purrr` using [these](https://www.r-exercises.com/2018/01/12/functional-programming-with-purrr-exercises-part-1/) exercises.

The task (exercise 8) is the following:

1. Split the `mtcars` dataset by `cyl`.
2. Fit a linear model (`qsec ~ hp` for each group of observations by `cyl`.
3. Fit each model to all `mtcars`.

My current code is:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
    split(mtcars$cyl) %>% 
    map(~ lm(.x$qsec ~ .x$hp)) %>% 
    map(~ predict(.x, newdata = list(mtcars)))
```

However, this only applies one model on one group of `mtcars`, so that the output is:

```
$`4`
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
18.98872 19.43308 18.96005 19.37574 19.57642 19.39008 18.93138 19.37574 
       9       10       11 
19.01739 18.70203 18.75937 

$`6`
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7 
18.51998 18.51998 18.51998 18.74090 17.94558 17.94558 15.64799 

$`8`
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
17.37861 16.13783 17.28998 17.28998 17.28998 16.84684 16.66959 16.40371 
       9       10       11       12       13       14 
17.82174 17.82174 16.13783 17.37861 15.80104 14.54254
```

The desired output, as I understand it, would be a list of predicted values with three list elements of 32 values each. How would I need to revise the code? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you passed the vectors directly into the formula inside `lm()`. Instead pass the dataset to the `data=` argument:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.3.1

pred <- mtcars %>%
  split(mtcars$cyl) %>%
  map(~ lm(qsec ~ hp, data = .x)) %>%
  map(~ predict(.x, newdata = mtcars))

lapply(pred, length)
#> $`4`
#> [1] 32
#> 
#> $`6`
#> [1] 32
#> 
#> $`8`
#> [1] 32
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for the fast clarification, Stefan!

Comment: to keep the tidyverse style we could do: `library(tidyverse)

pred <- mtcars %>%
  group_split(cyl) %>%
  map(~ lm(qsec ~ hp, data = .x)) %>%
  map(~ predict(.x, newdata = mtcars))

map(pred, length)`

Comment: @TarJae. Sure. Still I prefer using `split` as it returns a named list whereas `group_split` does not.

Comment: Interesting, thank you both. I vaguely remembered that a `tidyverse` function existed but didn't bother to look it up. @Stefan I agree with you though, the named version seems more helpful in this case.

Comment: @stefan. that is a very good point!